# WoW change Cmd and Ctrl

Tags: world-of-warcraft, keyboard

Is it possible to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in World of warcraft? (Without changing it in the whole system).

I tried to google, but found only one unanswered topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, on the main menu navigate to the System options.  From there, select Keyboard Options on the left.  The second checkbox **Use Command key as Control key** is the one you want to enable:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea how I didn't noted this... I've looked all menu through.